# Asset Browser default library behaviour (Change from 'All' to 'Current File') [Blender 3.5]

Tags: asset-browser, settings

**Is it possible to change the asset browser's behaviour when opening asset browser in a new context?**

**Problem:**
By default in Blender 3.5, a new Asset Browser context will always open with all asset libraries listed (assuming you have setup your libraries)

**What I want:**
I want it to be set to the 'Current File' option instead

**Why?:**
I've set up multiple asset libraries and some libraries are lighter than others and I'd like to not load everything when I open a new asset browser context.

Thank you.